# Executable file won't execute

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to install a piece of software during an installation.
I decided to create a folder within the temp folder if it wasn't present to first store the executable file as from what I can tell `{tmp}` will create a random name, and I'm thinking that if i try and execute the file, using `{tmp}` again will only create a new random name

```
 // Check if utilites folder is in the temp folder
 // if not we will create it here so there are no
 // problems adding the files in the file section
 if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
    ForceDirectories(ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK'));
```

From there he is the `File Section`, using the `*` I'm hoping that that will get every file within that folder.

```
 Source: "{#ExternalInstallers}\Foo\SDK\*"; DestDir: "{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK";Flags:  recursesubdirs createallsubdirs ; check:InstallCheck('Foo')
```

and from there if the required boolean is set to true, the execution of the file should begin from `InitializeSetup()`

```
if({#GNTCChecked})then 
begin
    Log('Start installing SDK for Foo Plugin...');
     if not ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK\setup.exe'), ExpandConstant('/S /v/qn'), '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then//added 18-05-2018 GK
      begin
         MsgBox('Cannot install Foo SDK! Foo may not work properly! Error Code: ' +IntToStr(ErrorCode) ,mbInformation, MB_OK);              
         Log('Cannot install Foo SDK! Foo may not work properly!');  
      end;
      Log('Start installing CU7 for Foo Plugin...');
      if not ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK\FooBar.exe'), ExpandConstant('/S /v/qn'), '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then
      begin
         MsgBox('Cannot install CU7 for Foo! Foo  may not work properly! Error Code: ' +IntToStr(ErrorCode) ,mbInformation, MB_OK);             
         Log('Cannot install CU7 for Foo! Foo may not work properly!');  
      end; 
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

None of the message boxes that I have told it to show if there is a problem show, However the added on program that I'm wanting to install does install.

Comment: Unfortunately at this stage I was unable to find a fix, however I think it may be due to administration rights, so i ended up executing the files from the run section and with the administration problem I ended up add `ShellExec` to one of the `flags` of the file in order to get it to execute without any errors.